# Why my app crashes when I try to assign value of one vectors element to another vector element?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm very new to C++. I try to find vertices of my shape and draw circles around them. I draw circles in this line of main function:

```
drawVertices(getDrawingVertices(getAllPoints()), src_clone);
```

I think that everything is all right with my `drawVertices()` function:

```
void drawVertices(vector<Point> drawingVertices, Mat src_clone) {
    for( int i = 0; i < drawingVertices.size(); i++ ){
        circle(src_clone, drawingVertices[i], 5, Scalar(255), 3, 8);
    }
}
```

But not all right with `getDrawingVertices()` function. My app crashes when I try to assign value of one vectors element to another vectors element:

`drawingVertices[i] = pointsArray[topLength];`

Full code of function `getDrawingVertices()` is here:

```
vector<Point> getDrawingVertices (vector<Point> pointsArray) {
       int N = pointsArray.size();
       int numberOfDrawingVertices = 8;
       vector<Point> drawingVertices(numberOfDrawingVertices);
       vector<int> lengthArray(N);
       Point centerPoint = findCenter();

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        lengthArray[i] = floor(pow((pow((pointsArray[i].x - centerPoint.x),2) + 
        pow((pointsArray[i].y - centerPoint.y),2)),0.5));
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int topLength = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (lengthArray[j] > lengthArray[topLength]) {
                topLength = j;
            }
        }
        drawingVertices[i] = pointsArray[topLength];
        lengthArray[topLength] = 0;
   }
   return drawingVertices;
}
```

And here is the code of function `getAllPoints ()`:

```
vector<Point> getAllPoints () {
    vector<Point> pointsArray;
        for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ){
            for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++) {
                pointsArray.push_back(contours[i][j]);
            }
    }
    return pointsArray;
}
```

### Edit

Function `findCenter()`:

```
 Point findCenter() {

    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ){
        mu[i] = moments( contours[i], false );
    }
    vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
        mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 );
    }

    int SumX = 0;
    int SumY = 0;
    int pointCol = 0;
    for(int j= 0; j < mc.size();j++) {
       SumX += mc[j].x;
       SumY += mc[j].y;
       pointCol++;
    }

    Point centerPoint;
    centerPoint.x = floor(SumX/pointCol);
    centerPoint.y = floor(SumY/pointCol);
    return centerPoint;
}
```

Where I have a mistake?

Comment: What is the exception/error you get?

Comment: Are your sure that *N* < *numberOfDrawingVertices* ?

Comment: If `contours` is ever empty, then `pointsArray` may also be empty. At which point `pointsArray[topLength]` would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: @CaptainTrunky The code doesn't rely on any particular relationship between `N` and `numberOfDrawingVertices`. It only relies on `N > 0`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You'are right, misread the code.

Comment: What does `findCenter()` function do? Does it always return a value?

Comment: It's likely you're accessing something outside its bounds. Use a debugger to examine the variables when the crash happens, or use the `at()` function which performs range checking and should give you a more meaningful and immediate error when the out of bounds access happens.

Comment: @neur0tic I've edit the question.

Comment: The shown code still fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]. The most important C++ lesson you will ever learn: just because a C++ program crashes on a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Which is why you must provide a [mcve], that anyone can run and reproduce themselves, in order to analyze and determine the root cause of your crash. Welcome to C++.

Comment: That what I have in debugger output: SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x0)). In getDrawingVertices frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn to debug your code yourself.

If your app crashes at this line

```
drawingVertices[i] = pointsArray[topLength];
```

You should check the length of `drawingVertices` and `pointsArray`, as well as `i` and `topLength`.  Check that `i>=0`, `i<drawingVertices.size()`, and same for `pointsArray` and `topLength`.  If one of these condition does not obey, check when and how it becomes wrong.

(On a side note, instead of pow(x, 0.5) use sqrt(x). But it is not connected to your problem.)